# How to create columns from values of a data frame in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having a df that contains below values, would like to create columns for each values present in the df. Looking for a solution in pyspark.Basically I could do this with a case when in pyspark, looking for a different approach. Any suggestions will be helpful.

DF:

```
|number|color|
|------|-----|
|123   |red  |
|234   |blue |
|555   |white|
```

Expected output:

| number | red | blue | white |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 234 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 555 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

You can group by `number`, pivot by `color` and apply the `lit(1)` value. To removing null values, apply `[dataframe].na.fill(0)`

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  [123, 'red'],
  [234, 'blue'],
  [555, 'white']
], ['number', 'color'])

pivot_df = df.groupBy('number').pivot('color').agg(f.lit(1))
pivot_df = pivot_df.na.fill(0)

(pivot_df
 .select('number', 'red', 'blue', 'white')
 .sort('number')
 .show(truncate=False))
# +------+---+----+-----+
# |number|red|blue|white|
# +------+---+----+-----+
# |123   |1  |0   |0    |
# |234   |0  |1   |0    |
# |555   |0  |0   |1    |
# +------+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: agg(F.count("number")) will produce same result - right ? Did not understand the significance of lit(1)

Comment: @dsk If you have twice `123 red` will produce an output with value 2 instead. The OP is not clear about if he wants count or just set a boolean value